# "Dave Check" for a tweakable P-256 ECDH KDF

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, key-derivation

I have two devices with hardware tokens that contain P-256 private keys, and which allow me to compute ECDH shared secrets with arbitrary public keys. I need to build a tweakable key derivation function, which deterministically allows both sides to generate the same key given their partner's P-256 public key and a tweak value. The construction must have the property that computing the key for a new tweak value requires an operation on the hardware token, even if token outputs for many other tweak values are known.

I've come up with the following pseudocode:

```
// NIST recommended way to generate a private key
l = 2^256 − 432420386565659656852420866394968145599
P256Priv(ikm): (HKDF_expand(40, ikm) % (l - 1)) + 1

// point multiplication with g as the P-256 generator
P256Pub(p): g * p

// different function instances for different tokens
tokenECDH(inPub): ECDH(tokenPriv, inPub)

// Using XOR because it makes both sides symmetrical
TweakableKDF(tokenECDH, peerPub, tweak, numBytes):
    Epriv = P256Priv(tweak)
    Epub = P256Pub(Epriv)
    HKDF_expand(numBytes, tokenECDH(Epub) ^ ECDH(Epriv, peerPub))
```

It looks to me like this would be secure, but I don't want to [be a Dave](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25585/is-my-developers-home-brew-password-security-right-or-wrong-and-why). (Also, I can't help but wonder if there's something standard out there that does this already; I looked briefly and was surprised I didn't find much.)

Any Questions? Comments? Snide remarks?

Comment: Hmm, can your HW store an arbitrary amount of ECDH secrets? So e.g. two private keys?

Comment: @SEJPM Yep. There's a limit, IDK off the top of my head, but call it 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is broken, because possession of `Epriv` (a function of the public tweak value) allows calculation of the output of `tokenECDH(Epub)` given knowledge of `tokenPub` (another public value).

This is stupid obvious now, but it took several days to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are looking for is impossible.

To see this, let's formalize things a bit: You have an oracle (the HW token) $T(Q)=[x]Q$ which computes a scalar product of any given input point with a secret scalar. You have an integer (or a byte sequence) $t$ - the tweak - and you have a public point $Q'$ from your partner as well as of course a standard point for the curve $G$.

Now the question asks to find a KDF $K_T(t,Q')$ such that every change in the known input tuple $(t,Q')$ yields a completly unpredictable value. However your only ressource for that is the $T$ oracle and so if you compute it's input as $T(f(t,G))$ then you need to find a deterministic $f$ such that the discrete logarithm problem between $f(t,G)$ and $G$ is hard even if one knows $t$. Otherwise of course you can use your solution to just take $T(G)$ and apply the found discrete logarithm to that.

Comment: Aha, but I think I solved this yesterday! Specifically, there's no reason you need f to be a function of G. All you need it to do is turn t into a curve point: preferably in a "nothing-up-my-sleeve" manner that makes it clear that t' such that t'G = f(t) is unknown, perhaps by hashing it and massaging the bits somewhat.

Call your partner's public key Y = yG; then T(f(t)) * Y = x * f(t) * yG = y * f(t) * xG. In short, ECDH(Ypriv, ECDH(Xpriv, f(t))) = ECDH(Xpriv, ECDH(Ypriv, f(t))).

Comment: Of course, I'm just now realizing I've violated my own requirement for no communication. You need to get y * f(t) from your partner to make it work. Luckily, my application can handle a single message like that.